# Simple questions about a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Reading Pinter's algebra, I'm little bit confused. In ch.24, the author says that x which appears in a polynomial is to be considered as a 'placeholder' for a moment...

All right, then i was trying to solve the problem 'is x^8+1=x^3+1 in Z3[x]?'

Well i would say no if i can substitute some elements of z3 to x...but if x is just a 'placeholder' how should i solve the problem?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: For elements in a polynomial ring, you can view $x$ as an object or element of the polynomial ring. You can also evaluate a polynomial in which you can view $x$ as a variable.

Comment: So you mean i can replace x with the elements of the ring?

Comment: For instance, if you have the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, then an element of this ring is $2x^2 + 5x + 3$. $x$ is not an element of the ring $\mathbb{Z}$. That polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$. You can think of it as a ring extension. In your case, if you decided to evaluate the polynomial above, then yes, you can plug in values for it.

Answer (score 1):

When you see the polynomial as an object, then $x$ is a "placeholder". But you can also see the polynomial as a function, where you think of $x$ as a variable. The two notions agree (in the sense that if two polynomials are equal as functions then they are equal as polynomials) when the coefficient ring is $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$, or $\mathbb C$, but  they don't in general.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the difference between (formal) polynomials and polynomial functions.

A rigourous definition of a polynomial over a commutative ring $A$ is that, as a set, it is
$$A^{(\mathbf N)}=\bigl\{(a_0,a_1,\dots, a_k,\dots)\mid a_k\in A \text{ and all $a_k$ but a finite number are 0}\bigr\}$$
In other words, a polynomial is identified with the (infinite, but actually finite) sequence of its coefficients. The greatest $k$ such that $a_k\neq 0$, if any, is called the *degree* of the polynomial.

This set is endowed with two operations:

- an addition, defined componentwise;
- a multiplication defined as:
  $$(a_0,a_1,\dots, a_k,\dots)(b_0,b_1,\dots, b_k,\dots)=(ca_0,c_1,\dots, c_k,\dots)$$
  where
  $$c_k=a_0b_k+a_1b_{k-1}+\dots+a_kb_0$$
  One checks that this defines a *commutative ring* with zero element,:  $(0,0,\dots,0,\dots)$, and unit element $(1,0,\dots, 0,\dots)$.

Now to recover the traditional notation, the ring of polynomials over $A$ is a *free $A$-module* (if $A$ is a field, this means it's a vector space), with an infinite basis :
\begin{align*}
1&=(1,0,0,\dots, 0,\dots)\\
X&=(0,1,0,\dots,0,\dots)\\
X^2&=(0,0,1,\dots,0,\dots\\
\vdots\\
X^k&=(0,0,0,\dots,1,\dots)\\
\vdots
\end{align*}
So the polynomial $(a_0,a_1,\dots, a_d,0,\dots,0,\dots)$, $\,a_d\neq 0$ is no other than $\,a_0+a_1X+\dots+a_dX^d$.

Of course to each such formal polynomial $p(X)$, one can associate a *polynomial function* on the ring $A$, obtained by replacing the *indeterminate* $X$ with elements of $A$. This defines a *ring-homorphism* from the ring of polynomials $A[X]$ to the ring of polynomial functions. This ring homomorphism is an isomorphism if $A$ˆis an infinite domain.

An example of a nonzero polynomial, giving rise to the zero function is, for a prime number $p$ and the field $\mathbf F_p=\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$:
$$p(X)=X^p-X$$
For all $x\in\mathbf F_p$, $p(x)=0$ is just Little Fermat.

Answer (score 1):

Put in very simple terms, as *polynomials* two polynomials are equal if and only if *all their coefficients are the same*.

So in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$, we have:

$x^8 + 1 \neq x^3 + 1$,

because the coefficient of $x^8$ in the first is $1$, but the coefficient of $x^8$ is $0$ in the second (it *has* no $x^8$ term).

However, in $\Bbb Z_3$, we *do* have an $a \in \Bbb Z_3$ with:

$a^8 + 1 = a^3 + 1$, namely: $a = 0$.

Once needs to be careful, here; even though $x^3 - x$ and $x^4 - x^2$ agree on all possible values in $\Bbb Z_3$, they are NOT the same polynomial in $\Bbb Z_3[x]$.